# Vector drawable loading in RecyclerView

Tags: android, caching, android-recyclerview, picasso

I need to load VectorDrawable resources depending on different cases into imageviews in recycler-view. The current implementation instantiates a new drawable everytime, which i am sure, leads to performance loss with a huge amount of items in the list. I want to change it, so that drawables are reused effectively to reduce the amount of created objects. I am using Picasso and i thought it could be a good idea to delegate this work to it, but it looks like Picasso is not able to load VectorDrawable's. Is there a way to manage this?

UPD.
The resource is loaded using ContextCompat.getDrawable and set using setImageDrawable. ImageView drawable is cleared in onViewRecycled

Comment: show some code to see what you are doing?

Comment: @KaveeshKanwal there isn't much code. The resource is loaded using **ContextCompat.getDrawable** and set using **setImageDrawable**. ImageView drawable is cleared in **onViewRecycled**. The thing is that **ContextCompat.getDrawable** is called everytime which leads to object construction.

Comment: I want to know if there is a way to cache drawables throught whole application for the later use.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution i can think of is to move the loading of dynamic drawable images from the UI thread to the background thread. To make the loading smoother, you need to load the images Asynchronously using an AsyncTask in your adapter. This will take the load off the UI thread and make the user experience much better. You are not able to use Picasso, hence i recommend a simple AsyncTask.

I found a good snippet for this, have a look:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView,
        ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;

    ...

    holder.position = position;

    new ThumbnailTask(position, holder)
            .executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, null);

    return convertView;
}

private static class ThumbnailTask extends AsyncTask {
    private int mPosition;
    private ViewHolder mHolder;

    public ThumbnailTask(int position, ViewHolder holder) {
        mPosition = position;
        mHolder = holder;
    }

    @Override
    protected Cursor doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // Download bitmap here
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (mHolder.position == mPosition) {
            mHolder.thumbnail.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }
}

private static class ViewHolder {
    public ImageView thumbnail;
    public int position;
}
```

For more info, please have a look at [this](http://lucasr.org/2012/04/05/performance-tips-for-androids-listview/) link.